# unable to push to queue created by static map<struct, queue>

Tags: c++, static, dictionary, struct, queue

So basically I have a static map that maps my struct to a queue, but when I try to push to the queue, it fails to push anything.

```
struct SignalID_t {
    unsigned int lock;
    unsigned int cond;

    SignalID_t(unsigned int lock_, unsigned int cond_):lock(lock_), cond(cond_) {}
};

class SignalIDComp {
public:
bool operator()(const SignalID_t& a, const SignalID_t& b) const
    {return a.lock == b.lock && a.cond == b.cond;}
}; 

class ThreadManager{
public:

static std::queue<ucontext_t *>& waitingQ(SignalID_t id)
    {return threadsWaitingOnConditions[id];}

private:
    static std::map<SignalID_t, std::queue<ucontext_t*>> threadsWaitingOnConditions;
}

map<SignalID_t, queue<ucontext_t *>, SignalIDComp>    ThreadManager::threadsWaitingOnConditions;

class Threads{

void thread_wait(int lock, int cond){
    SignalID_t id(lock, cond);
    ThreadManager::waitingQ(id).push(ThreadManager::getRunningThread());
    if (ThreadManager::waitingQ(id).empty())
       cout << "failed to push thread to cond waiting Q" << endl;
}
}
```

In the function where I try to push to the queue, I immediately test the queue to see if it's empty and it always cout's that it is. I suspect that it may have something to do with the fact that the map is static and the queue isn't getting initialized properly, but I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: This is not real code: class definitions have to be terminated by semicolons, and there is no `ThreadManager::getRunningThread()`. Please post real code.

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate, and unfortunately identically-named, objects:

```
map_type ThreadManager::threadsWaitingOnConditions;
```

and

```
map_type threadsWaitingOnConditions;
```

You're confusing the two. The final check should say:

```
if (ThreadManager::threadsWaitingOnConditions[id].empty()) { /* ... */ }
```

or something to that effect. Given that the static member map is private, you should probably just say,

```
if (ThreadManager::waitingQ(id).empty()) { /* ... */ }
```

I don't understand what need you have with the global map object. It seems unnecessary. Or rather, you probably mean it to be the *definition* of the static member object, in which case you should write it like this:

```
map<SignalID_t, std::queue<ucontext_t*>> ThreadManager::threadsWaitingOnConditions;
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Ah sorry about that, but most of those things were a reflection of my manually recreating the code instead of copying and pasting it. I believe the current state of the question reflects most of those changes, and the push still fails to work.

Comment: OK, your current code shouldn't even compile, though, since you don't have a function `ThreadManager::getRunningThread()`. I should ask you to post real code from your work rather than half-remembered pseudo-code, though, as it's impossible to separate what is the real error and what is an error of presentation.